# Whether it is possible hide 'checkbox' with use th:unless?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a color filter, simillar to this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="orange" class="orange"  value="orange"/>orange
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox"  id="peach"   value="peach"/>peach
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="terracotta"   value="terracotta"/>terracotta
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="coffee"   value="coffee"/>coffee
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="browne"  value="browne"/>browne
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rose"  value="rose"/>rose
            <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="red"   value="red"/>red
            <br/>
```

I recive color from DB.

```
<div th:each="model : ${allColor}">

                            <span th:text="${model.color}"/>
```

Can I hide color, with use Thymeleaf, which is not in DB?
For example now I haven't Rose, Coffee and Peach colors, but maybe in future I will have this color. I want to do colors verification , if color is in DB, user can see on UI checkbox, else checkbox hide. I read about `th:if` and `th:unless`. Whether it is possible to make it with use Thymeleaf?

If I try to do:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:if="${model.color==coffee}"id="coffee"   value="coffee"/>coffee
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding colors, you should create the color checkboxes with a loop as well. Like this:

```
<th:block th:each="model : ${allColor}" th:with="color=${model.color}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:id="${color}" th:class="${color}" th:value="${color}"/> <span th:text="${color}" />
    <br />
</th:block>
```

As for why your original attempt didn't work, it's hard to tell without seeing more of the html.  I'm guessing that ${model.color} was undefined, because you weren't in a loop?  Also, you were missing quotes around 'coffee'. like this: `${model.color == 'coffee'

Something like this may work as well, but I would recommend the loop.

```
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('orange')}" type="checkbox" id="orange" class="orange" value="orange"/>orange<br/>
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('peach')}" type="checkbox" id="peach" value="peach"/>peach<br/>
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('terracotta')}" type="checkbox" id="terracotta" value="terracotta"/>terracotta<br/>
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('coffee')}" type="checkbox" id="coffee" value="coffee"/>coffee<br/>
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('browne')}" type="checkbox" id="browne" value="browne"/>browne<br/>
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('rose')}" type="checkbox" id="rose" value="rose"/>rose<br/>
<input th:if="${allColor.contains('red')}" type="checkbox" id="red" value="red"/>red<br/>}`.
```

Comment: `<input th:if="${allColor.contains('orange')}" type="checkbox" id="orange" class="orange" value="orange"/>orange` in this variant I can't see `checkbox`, I see like a `span`

Comment: Is `allColor` a List<String>?  Oh, you'll have to convert allColor to a list of string if you want this to work.

Comment: `<th:block th:each="model : ${allColor}" th:with="color: ${model.color}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:id="${color}" th:class="${color}" th:value="${color}"/> <span th:text="${color}" />
    <br />
</th:block>` On this part code I recive:
**Could not parse as assignation sequence: "color: ${curtain.color}"** Maybe becouse I have in `allColor` name, color, id

Comment: Sorry, `th:with="color: ${model.color}"` should be `th:with="color=${model.color}"`, typo there.

Comment: `allColor` = `List<ColorDTO> dtos = colorService.seeAllColor();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("allColor",dtos);`, `ColorDTO` = id, name, description, color

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers. I have one problem becouse I have name and color. Several name can have one color and I recive several checkbox with one color